# How can i download and use geocoder v3

Tags: java, google-maps

I am using eclipse kepler and want to use geocoder.
I tried to download but with no success.

How can i download and use geocoder v3 ?
the project link : [geocoder-java](https://code.google.com/p/geocoder-java/)

What kind of plugin or software do I need to use (m2eclipse or tortoisesvn)?
and how I do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In eclipse you want to download plugin for google maps...

Comment: r u doing working with  android or phone gap technology..........